# how to return number of rows in SQL Join from first table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a comments table:

[image]

Another Table is review :

[image]

I want to display all comments data (with avg from review table)  where company, city, state, country and private=0 match.

I tried:

```
SELECT c.* , p.avg FROM comments c,review p WHERE c.`username`=p.`username` AND c.`company`='10x Technology' AND c.`city`='Libertyville' AND c.`state`='IL' AND c.`country`='USA' AND private=0
```

I get the following output:

[image]

**But This is wrong because there is only 1 testing Comment.**

**Is there a way to show same number of comments that match without repeating**

Its showing total rows from both table, I want same rows from comment table.

Hope I have made is easy to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Of the four review entries which avg would you like and what would be the logic for selecting it.

Comment: Look up this Documentation about the `JOIN` Statement. This should help you getting only the Returned rows from one table. A simple `LEFT JOIN`should fix it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select one record from Table comments. But you're also trying to get alle match records from Table review. Table review has for the username 'WWW' 5 records. So you will get through your SQL-Statment 5 records. If you want only to get the one record from Table comments and only avg from Table review, try this Code.

```
SELECT c.* , 
(select p.avg FROM review p 
where 
p.`username`= c.`username` AND 
p.`company`= c.`company` AND 
p.`city`= c.`city` AND 
p.`state`= c.`state` AND 
p.`country`= c.`country` LIMIT 1) AS avg

FROM comments c

WHERE 
c.private=0
```

Remember that, you have more than one match in then table review!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want the last row from review so something like this might do (-note if you had provided data as text instead of images I would have provided a solution based on your data)

```
drop table if exists comment;
create table comment(id int,`comment` varchar(10), company varchar(3), state varchar(3), private int);

drop table if exists review;
create table review (id int,avg int,company varchar(3),state varchar(3));

insert into comment values (1,'Test','abc','il',0),(1,'Ver','def','il',0);

insert into review values(1,0,'abc','il'),(2,4,'abc','il'),(3,0,'def','il');

MariaDB [sandbox]> select c.*, r.avg
    -> from comment c
    -> join review r on c.company = r.company and c.state = r.state
    -> where c.`comment` = 'Test' and c.private = 0 and
    -> r.id = (select max(r1.id) from review r1 where r1.company = r.company and r1.state = r.state)
    -> ;
+------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
| id   | comment | company | state | private | avg  |
+------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
|    1 | Test    | abc     | il    |       0 |    4 |
+------+---------+---------+-------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```